# Serve remote url with node.js stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, safari, video-streaming, node.js-stream

I have a video stored in amazon s3.

Now I'm serving it to the client with node.js stream

`return request(content.url).pipe(res)`

But, the following format is not working with safari.

Safari is unable to play streamed data. But, the same code works for chrome and firefox.

I did some research and found out

chrome's request content-range param looks like

> [0-]

But, safari does the same with content ranges

> [0-10][11-20][21-30]

Now if the content was stored in my server, I could have break the file in chucks with

```
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
```

to serve safari with it's requested content range

As mentioned in this blog https://medium.com/better-programming/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6

**How can I do the same with remote url stored in s3?**

FYI, It's not feasible to download the content temporarily on server and delete it after serving. As, the website is supposed to receive good traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do the same with remote url stored in s3?

Don't.

Let S3 serve the data.  Sign a URL to temporarily allow access to the client.  Then, you don't have to serve or proxy anything and you save a lot of bandwidth.  An example from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property):

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url);
```

> ...As, the website is supposed to receive good traffic.

You'll probably also want to use a CDN to further reduce your costs and enhance the performance.  If you're already using AWS, [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/) is a good choice.